# AngularJS. Биндинг переменных

Tags: javascript, angularjs

По каким причинам рекомендуется использовать двойное двоеточие в ангуляровом биндинге - `{{::vm.title}}`?

Мой эксперимент на понимание смысла этого выражения провалился. Делал так:

```
/* Controller */
  ...
  var vm = this;

  vm.name = 'Vasya'
  ...

/* View */  
  ...  
  <div class="name" ng-click="vm.name = 'Petya'">
     {{::vm.name}}
  </div>
```

То есть, если $digest цикл пропускает {{::vm.name}} благодаря ::, то имя не должно меняться на Petya после клика на этот блок, но оно все равно изменяется. Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данный метод называется *oneway binding*, суть его заключается в том, что после того как наблюдаемая переменная получила какое-либо значение - наблюдатель убирается.

Поэтому этот подход должен применяться для случаев, когда показываемое значение получается один раз, например при загрузке, и больше не меняется.
Это позволяет снизить количество наблюдателей и облегчить digest-цикл.

Пример:

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('ctrl',function(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.name = 'Vasya';
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm" ng-init="vm.i=0">
  <input type="button" value="click" ng-click="vm.i= vm.i+1" />
  <div> меняется: {{vm.i}}</div>
  <div> не меняется: {{::vm.i}}</div>
  <input type="button" value="cahnge name" ng-click="vm.name = 'Petya'" />
  <div> name {{::vm.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, так я и понимал, но вот какая штука: когда я биндю некое значение через двоеточие а потом меняю его, например, по клику на какой-нибудь элемент, то оно изменяется даже несмотря на то, что digest его якобы пропускает. $scope при этом я не использую, а юзаю this в контроллере. Как так?

Comment: @Harvey, можете пример кода показать? и как проверяете?

Comment: @Harvey, добавил простой пример.

Comment: @Harvey, добавил в пример - ваш код с именами

Comment: Да, я не соблел чистоту эксперимента :) Мой пример выше действительно работает, а я на самом деле на другом примере проверял)
Спасибо